# I am trying to show multiple data on an android list view

Tags: android, listview

I try to show multiple data on an android list view screen, but my problem is the data keeps breaking the column lines instead of showing up in proper columns.
Here is my XML:

```
    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:textAlignment="center"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is how the rows are defined:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- row.xml -->
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:paddingTop="4dip"
    android:paddingBottom="6dip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center">



    <TextView android:id="@+id/FROM_CELL"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/FROMTIME_CELL"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/TOTIME_CELL"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/TITLE_CELL"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The different columns on the screen never come up on the same column but are shifted to the right by the exact length of the data in its preceeding column. Please let me know how to take care of this.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I cannot seem to be able to add a screenshot here, please let know if there is a possibility.

Comment: You have to upload to tinypic or somewhere :)

Comment: @cbandroid I have uploaded the answer try that it will help you ... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this it will work fine ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/txt_userName"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="19dp"
android:layout_weight="2"
android:gravity="center" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/txt_fName"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="19dp"
android:layout_weight="2" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/txt_lName"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="19dp"
android:layout_weight="3.51"
android:gravity="left" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and in second xml try this code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

<View
android:id="@+id/a"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:paddingBottom="10dp" />

<ListView
android:id="@+id/List"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it hepls ....

Comment: @cbandroid can you accept it as an answer and upvote it please so that other can also get help and me also ... :)

Comment: I accepted it, but I cannot up-vote since I do not have enough reputation, I guess its because I am new here...sorry about that :)